# Unable to access node server with DNS

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, dns

I'm running into this weird issue. 
I have my node server running in an EC2 instance over port number 6001.

I get a 200 when I use my EC2 ip over that port, i.e. `http://<instance_ip>:6001`. I then registered my instance IP to a subdomain say `http://node.example.com`.

Now, I try to access my node application using `http://node.example.com:6001` but it keeps timing out. I have already added an inbound rule in my EC2 security groups to allow TCP over 6001 from anywhere. But I'm still not able to get a 200 when I use my DNS.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: Is `node.example.com` resolving to `<instance_ip>`?

Comment: yes it is because I have an nginx server running on port 80, and that works well.

Comment: ping both <subdomain> and <instance dns> for Ip. both should end with same IP. there may be DNS routing Issue.

Comment: Its the cloudflare. Cloudflare only allows a set of ports to work with. 6001 is not among those. I changed the port number to 8080 and it worked.